# Oracle (+) Joins converting to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that uses the old style Oracle join syntax. I'm trying to convert this to T-SQL to reflect a data storage change.

My query is:

```
SELECT
    client_name1,
    personal_business_ind,
    birth_date,
    sex
FROM 
    client ce,
    exclusions_endorsements ee
WHERE 
    ce.client_reference = :clientid
    AND ee.fourth_insert(+) = ce.client_reference
    AND ee.identification_code(+) = 'OCCP1'
ORDER BY
    ee.run_date_last_trans DESC;
```

Could anyone please help?

I have tried the following query but it doesn't seem to produce the correct output on SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    client_name1,
    personal_business_ind,
    birth_date,
    sex
FROM 
    client ce,
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    [CLOAS].[EE_ExclusionsEndorsements] ee ON ee.fourth_insert = ce.client_reference AND ee.identification_code = 'OCCP1'
WHERE 
    ce.client_reference = @clientid
ORDER BY
    ee.run_date_last_trans DESC;
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? There seems to be plenty of resources explaining this out there.

Comment: @DaleK See edit

Comment: That was close. You want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because you want to outer join ee to ce. There is also a comma too many after `FROM client ce`. On a side note: right outer joins can make queries very hard to read. Don't use them. Always write your from clause such that you use left outer joins instead. Another side note: It is surprising that the result gets ordered by an ee column. If I remember correctly SQL Server treats nulls as the smallest possible value, so the block of outer-joined rows (and those with no date if any) comes last in your query result.

Comment: Wow... am Oracle query from the early 90s. I haven't seen these ones for ages.

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to produce the correct output on SQL Server" - Why have us guessing what this may mean? There is a syntax error in your query, so you probably get an error message that you could show us. Or, with the comma removed, you'd get results that look different from what you expected. In that case tell us *how* they look different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. But the outer joined table is `exclusions_endorsements`, not `client`, so you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. And there is a comma too many after `FROM client ce` in your query.

One more point: Oracle sorts nulls first when ordering descendingly, SQL Server sorts them last. And SQL Server does not support standard SQL syntax `NULLS FIRST`. We need a case expression hence.

```
SELECT
    client_name1,
    personal_business_ind,
    birth_date,
    sex
FROM client ce
LEFT OUTER JOIN exclusions_endorsements ee
                  ON ee.fourth_insert = ce.client_reference
                 AND ee.identification_code = 'OCCP1'
WHERE 
    ce.client_reference = @clientid
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ee.run_date_last_trans IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    ee.run_date_last_trans DESC;
```

I should add that the query would look better, did you qualify all columns. E.g. `ce.client_name1`. And sorting by a column you don't select can make the result look completely unordered. Well, maybe it's a non-nullable column, in that case it would just serve to get the outer-joined rows separated from the inner-joined rows in the result.

Comment: I almost put the last join predicate in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

That's "old" Oracle outer join operator. For example:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, max(e.ename) ename
  2  from dept d, emp e
  3  where e.deptno (+) = d.deptno
  4  group by d.deptno
  5  order by d.deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 MILLER
        20 SMITH
        30 WARD
        40
```

You'd - instead - use

```
SQL> select d.deptno, max(e.ename) ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  group by d.deptno
  4  order by d.deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 MILLER
        20 SMITH
        30 WARD
        40

SQL>
```

---

Or, in your case,

```
SELECT
    client_name1,
    personal_business_ind,
    birth_date,
    sex
FROM exclusions_endorsements ee left join client ce on ee.fourth_insert = ce.client_reference
                                                   AND ee.identification_code = 'OCCP1'
WHERE 
    ce.client_reference = :clientid   
ORDER BY
    ee.run_date_last_trans DESC;
```

Comment: If the "+" goes with the unpreserved table (emp in your first example), then isn't client the preserved table and exclusions the unpreserved table? So there should be a left join from client to exclusions? And referring to the unpreserved table (client in your suggested conversion) will force the outer join into an inner join.